# Iterating fields in dataclass that contains enums

Tags: python, python-3.x, enums, python-dataclasses

I'm writing a routine that iterates all the fields in a dataclass.  For each field that has a value it's added to a separate list.

The problem I have is that one of the fields is an enum.  I can assert its datatype as an enum, but I can't access the usual .name and .value properties.  Is it possible to cast the field to get access to the properties I'm after?

```
fields =[field, value) for field, vlaue in vars(temp_dto).items() if not field.startswith('__']

params_dict = {}

for name, value in fields:
    if value != None:
       params_dict.update({name : value})
       if issubclass(type(value),enum.Enum):
           print(value)

>> status.OPEN
```

Dataclass

```
class status(Enum):
    OPEN = 1
    CLOSED = 2
    RESTRICTED = 3


@dataclass
class AccountDto:
    account_id: int
    name: str
    region: str
    status: status
```

Comment: Could you add your dataclass definition too?

Comment: Actually it works for me, I can write sucessfuly `value.name` and `value.value`

Comment: LOl ohh lord! You're right, it does work.  My editors intellisense was telling me it wouldnt and took that for gospel.  arrrrghhh moral of story, don't trust intellisense :D

Answer (score 1):

Just an addon, for dynamically typed things your IDE can have a problem with guessing types, but typing library comes with a [cast](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.cast)

```
from enum import Enum
from typing import cast

class E(Enum):
    a = "A"

class F:
    pass


def create(s: str):
    if s == "e":
        return E("A")
    if s == "f":
        return F


x = create("e")
print(x.name) # mypy shows Cannot access member "name" for type "Type[F]"
x = cast(E, x)
print(x.name) # it works!
```

Answer (score 0):

Non issue, was caused by error with intellisense.